# SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

Есть activity с RelativeLayout и мне надо сделать так, чтобы при свайпе данные обновлялись, но при добавлении `<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` на экране ничего не появляется. Что мне надо изменить в коде, чтобы всё заработало?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/updated_field"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</ScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: а что вы обновлять хотите? не очень правильно помещать scrollView внутрь swipe layout

Comment: @Andrew, а что плохого в scrollView внутри swipe layout? Вроде как это как раз правильно. Проблема в разметке скорее в ширине-высоте элементов

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, просто насколько я знаю нельзя размещать то что скроллится внутри того что скроллится, или я путаю) Во всяком случае со списками такое не прокатывает, думал может и тут в этом может быть проблема :(

Comment: @Andrew, про вкладывания скролящихся контейнеров - верно, однако SwipeRefresh - не скролящийся контейнер, но контейнер с реакцией на скролл и как раз предназначен для оборачивания контейнеров, в т.ч. скролящихся)